# CPU Usage spikes up on Apache Ignite server Node

Tags: ignite

I am using Apache Ignite for in-memory cache usecase. I deployed Ignite in containerized environment with 4 nodes as server and 12 nodes as client.
Ignite Version: 2.15.0
JDK: 11

Recently I observed that when suddenly more number of users starts accessing application, CPU usage of Ignite servers gets increased to 100% and most of the time it never goes down till we restart pods. Sometimes CPU usage goes down automatically and application is accessible.

When CPU usage becomes high, I observed below exception while reading data from cache (not sure why locking is applicable even while reading data from cache):
*java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport:park
jdk.internal.misc.unsafe:park*

We are using default configuration of Cache:
mode=REPLICATE
atomicity=ATOMIC
default eviction policy.

Can somebody guide me how to resolve this issue?

One observation: I never had this issue with JDK 8 (but again its observation).